# How to call uncompleted tasks with google tasks api python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-tasks-api

I was wondering how I can call a list of my uncompleted tasks using the google tasks api. I currently am using the example code found at https://developers.google.com/tasks/quickstart/python and I'm wondering how I can adapt this to list tasks not tasklists. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 1):

I get that you took that [Tasks API quickstart](https://developers.google.com/tasks/quickstart/python) as a base and you want to change its functionality to list tasks instead of a tasklist. If I understood the situation correctly, then you are very close to reaching your target. You only need to know the tasklist identifier. Then, you can use it in the method [`tasks.list()`](https://developers.google.com/tasks/reference/rest/v1/tasks/list) to get a list of tasks within that tasklist. Don't hesitate to ask me any further doubts.

Comment: Thank you so much, do I just take this code results = service.tasklists().list(maxResults=10).execute()
    items = results.get('items', [])
And change it to service.task() at the beginning?

Comment: @Paddyxl yes, please test it and write back sharing your findings. If your final code doesn't fulfill your goals, please post it and I will take a look.